# visual studio and .net 3.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have multiple versions of .Net installed on my machine. I need my current Visual Studio project to use .net 3.5 dlls, is there an automatic way of doing this? Or do I need to manually remove and add references? Also I am missing a lot of dlls in .net 3.5.

Appreciate the help,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net 3.5 is not a complete framework, it is an addition to .net 3, which is an extension of .net 2 (adding WCF etc)

[Wikipedia's .NET 3.5 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5)

Right click the project and select properties and select the Target Framework from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Change IIS entry as following:
1. In IIS select your local website
2. Right click and select properties
3. In ASP.Net tab select ASP.Net version as 3.5

Configure VS for debugging:
1.Open web project in Visual studio
2. Select Website ->start Options
3. Choose **Build** from left hand menu and select **Target Framework** as .Net Framework 3.5

This should take care of it.